# Printing in Chrome, page-break-before causes some spaces, but doesn't go to next page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

Im trying to have a page break between two elements when printing. I used an empty div element:

```
<div>content 1</div>
<div style="page-break-before: always"></div>
<div>content 2</div>
```

This works perfectly in edge and internet explorer, but not in chrome. By adding the page-break before, some spaces between content 1 and 2 appear, but content 2 still has some part remain in page 1:

[image]

If i remove the page-break-before, they stick back together:[image]

How do i make a page break in chrome?

Comment: Have you tried `break-before`, I think that has replaced `page-break-before`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before - don't think it is well supported though

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried break-before but it seems chrome doesn't recognize it. It says invalid property value when i inspect the css

Comment: Not sure what else to try - seems they are removing this functionality

Comment: One interesting thing is that If i use * {  overflow: initial !important;}, the page break works

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a non empty div for `page-break-before` to work.
See the documentation [here](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_print_pagebb.asp):

> You cannot use this property on an empty div or on absolutely positioned elements.

I usually add dumb content inside the div and then set `opacity: 0`. You cannot set `display: none` because `page-break` only applies to block elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `<br pagebreak="true"/>` instead -> this does not add space on top of the page